# Email on iPhone not interpreting HTML

Tags: iphone, html, email, formatting

I've create a web app for a client that sends out a verification email. The email is formatted correctly when received through Gmail and other standard mail clients (on Macs and PCs).

But I have reports that it is not formatted correctly on the iPhone - it's showing all the HTML source. I thought this might be because the user had set their app to read emails as text only, but this does not seem to be the case.

I was just wondering if there is anything that I need to do as the author of the mail to make sure it's interpreted correctly on the iPhone. Note, I'm having no problems on my Android device - email looks as it should.

I've done a bit of googling on this and haven't found anything significant.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: Do you set the correct content-type for the html-part?

Comment: It's set to: text/html; charset=us-ascii at the moment, is this correct ?

Comment: I'd go with UTF-8. You might want to see the source of the email and compare to one of the working html mails.

Comment: Eiko, that didn't work, email is still the same. Any other thoughts ?

Comment: No idea... maybe post the source of the email so that we can have a look at it - not one of my favorite topics though. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the charset parameter of the mime document.  I know the standard is to put it, but iphone and imap authentification fails if this parameter is present... I hope it's the case for your email as well.